# What does (1,) mean in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I explored google [collab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/cc/exercises/linear_regression_with_synthetic_data.ipynb) and found that line:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, 
                                  input_shape=(1,)))
```

I think I know python 3 well, but I've never seen tuple like that (with empty end). I'm interested 1) Why it works? (no errors) 2) Is it usable for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the comma, then the language has no way to know whether you are
constructing a tuple, or just enforcing order of evaluation:

```
>>> (1)
1
```

The comma makes it explicit that you are defining a tuple:

```
>>> (1,)
(1,)
```

> Using a trailing comma for a singleton tuple: `a,` or `(a,)`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple